# Node.js - What does “socket hang up” mean in simple words?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to know what socket hang up means in very simple words.

Comment: Where are you seeing socket hang up

Comment: @JClassic I saw that question but it doesn't explain in simple words what socket hang up means. I don't have an example, I just want to know what it means

Answer (score 1):

Without a specific situation it's hard to say, but usually it means the communication between user and server failed, possibly due to too much time without a response.

Answer (score 1):

Socket hang up in simple term means that the connection establishment failed while making an attempt for it.

Why it happens - as you already know, is possible because of various reasons. Generally happens because the server becomes unresponsive hence the connection was never established as expected.